# Noble and white

Tags: riddle

> My sisters like it warmer,
>
> I survive in the cold.
>
> The others are low.
>
> But high I grow.
>
> Yet I am not tall.
>
> I am small, noble and white.
>
> Many seek me -
>
> A few see me, a few die.
>
> Some strongly protect me,
>
> Others sing songs in my name.

What am I?

Comment: I always feel like the answers to these will be some rare mystical plant haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Edelweiss?

My sisters like it warmer,

> The flowers prefer warmer climate

I survive in the cold.

> But the edelweiss grows in the cold mountains

The others are low.

> The other flowers are low-er, i.e. in the planes

But high I grow.

> But the edelweiss grows high in the mountain

Yet I am not tall.

> Though it is a fairly small flower

I am small, noble and white.

> It is, indeed, the plant is small and in German edel-weiss means noble-white

Many seek me -

> It is a popular thing to search for in the mountains

A few see me, a few die.

> Some see it, unfortunately the mountains could be dangerous

Some strongly protect me,

> It is a protected plant in many countries

Others sing songs in my name.

> There are popular songs in its [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edelweiss_(song)).

Comment: Now only say why it is noble and white. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva Check my update.